# Initial value for Pandas ewm mean

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to set the initial value when computing an exponentially weighted moving average using pandas ewm.mean?

pandas ewm.mean initializes at the first value of the series - can I set/override the initial value?

See code example:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([5, 1, 2, 4, 3])
alpha = 0.2

# computing the exponential mean using pandas ewm.mean:
a = s.ewm(alpha=alpha, adjust=False).mean()

# iterative solution with the same result:
b = pd.Series()
z = 5  # initial value
for i, x in s.items():
    z = alpha * x + (1 - alpha) * z
    b.loc[i] = z

# behaviour I want, i.e. initialize at a specific value:
c = pd.Series()
z = 3  # initial value
for i, x in s.items():
    z = alpha * x + (1 - alpha) * z
    c.loc[i] = z

print(pd.concat([s, a, b, c], axis=1, keys=['unsmoothed', 'pandas', 'iterative', 'initialized (the result I want)']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas ewm doesn't seem to have support for an initial value. Here's a workaround I use if I have to use ewm. Just append the initial value to the start of the unsmoothed series and then truncate the first value of your smoothed series.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([5, 1, 2, 4, 3])
alpha = 0.2

# workaround:
z = 3  # initial value
x = pd.concat([pd.Series([z]), s])
w = x.ewm(alpha=alpha, adjust=False).mean().iloc[1:]

print(pd.concat([s, w], axis=1, keys=['unsmoothed', 'smoothed with ewm (workaround)']))
```